# Progressive Dice Game

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, game-theory, dice

**$(2019.)$ Edit:** Rewriting the question to make it clear.

---

**The progressive dice game**

> At the start, you have a fair, regular six sided dice $D=(1,2,3,4,5,6)$.
>
> The game is played for $n$ turns. Each turn you make a roll, which will be $r\in D$.
>
> Then to complete the turn, you make one of the following choices:
>
> - **Bank** the rolled number: You gain $r$ points (score).
> - **Invest in (upgrade)** the dice *"evenly"*: If $r\lt 6$, choose $r$ sides and increase them by $1$ each. If $r\ge 6$, that is, $r=6k+k_0,k_0\lt 6$, then increase each of the six sides by $k$, and then choose $k_0$ sides and increase them by $1$ each.
> - **Reroll** the dice, effectively restarting this turn. But before rerolling, you must apply the penalty to the dice: *"Evenly"* **downgrade** the dice: If $S_0$ is the number of sides $\gt 0$ on the dice, then: If $r\lt S_0$, choose $r$ sides and decrease them by $1$ each. If $r\ge S_0$, that is, $r=S_0k+k_0,k_0\lt S_0$, then decrease each of the $S_0$ sides by $k$, and then choose $k_0$ sides and decrease them by $1$ each.
>
> What is the optimal way to play to maximize your expected score at the end of the game?

If the dice was allowed to be upgraded/downgraded arbitrarily (not "evenly"), then one could downgrade the first five sides until they reach $0$. These sides now act as free rerolls. Then, keep investing the remaining points into the sixth side, which is now guaranteed to be rolled on each turn, after some amount of rerolls of that turn. Finally, bank that sixth rolled side in the last couple turns to maximize the expected value of the score.

But since we must upgrade/downgrade evenly, I'm not sure what is the optimal strategy.

**If we ignore the "reroll" move:**

If you upgrade the first $t$ turns, then bank the rest of the turns, you will expect the following amount of points on average:
$$ f(t) = 3.5\times\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)^{t}\times(n-t)$$

Which boils down to, that if you want to maximize your expected score, you should upgrade until the last $6$ (or $7$) turns and then bank those turns.

But this approach completely ignores the third action; the rerolls.

> Can we do better than this strategy, if we use the rerolls somehow?

---

**Rerolls?**

I haven't worked out the strategy if the rerolls are considered.

A reroll will on average decrease the average value of the dice, and allow you to either improve or worsen your current turn, with equal probability on average?

But there seem to be exceptions? For example, rerolling a $1$ seems useful if used early (as later, if we had upgraded a lot, all sides will be much greater than $1$). Simply downgrade the rolled $1$ side when downgrading (rerolling). If you roll that side again, it will be $0$, and this allows you to again reroll the dice for free (downgrading $0$ points is a free reroll). Which means, choosing to downgrade when you roll a $1$, can only increase your expected score in that turn. But there is still a (small?) drawback: Lets say some other side is a number $\ge 6$. Then when upgrading later, you will have to put back at least one of those upgrade points into that downgraded $0$ side.

> Seems to me that rerolls will decrease the expected score on average
>   (as they decrease the average value of the dice), so it is always
>   better not to use them (except in that early scenario of the game, if $n$ is small)? Is this true?

For example, for small $n$, rerolls can be useful to force larger values. For $n=1$ specifically, it seems we can always force the first turn (the only turn) to end up banking a $6$, the maximal possible score for $n=1$, by rerolling and downgrading strategically the rest of the sides if $6$ was not rolled.

But for large $n$, the rerolls seem to lower the average expected score at the end, if used anytime in previous turns, as larger upgrades will need to replenish those downgraded points inevetably at some point, as they are carried out "evenly".

Comment: Can you be more specific about the meaning of "[increment] its sides distributing the points one by one" and "downgrade the dice evenly taking one by one point"?  Are you incrementing/decrementing all sides by one?  Just the smallest/largest side?

Comment: @mjqxxxx You do one side by one point, then repeat for another side, till you use up all your points that were rolled, if you do all sides and have points left to spent, you do the same with the remaining points again. (Example; rolled $4$ = do $4$ sides, each by $1$ point, Example; $8$ = do all sides by one point, then do two sides by one point)

Comment: And in the downgrade you remove as many points as you'd rolled, and then effectively get a new turn, in which you have a new choice whether to bank, upgrade or downgrade?

Comment: You can't maximise your score, since this is a random variable. I suspect what you mean is to maximise the expected value of the score?

Comment: And for the downgrade: Does this also start over once you've taken a point off all sides? If there are sides with $0$, does the downgrade start over once you've taken a point off all non-zero sides, or do the zero sides count towards the points despite not being further downgraded?

Comment: Your formula seems right, but would be a bit easier to understand if you write it as $3.5\cdot\left(\frac76\right)^t(n-t)$.

Comment: @joriki Yes, a reroll is a new turn, more precisely it is starting your turn over, but with a bit downgraded dice. Yes, by maximise I tought of maximising the expected value, or in other words the average value over repeated games. Yes it "starts over", downgrade points work the same way as upgrades, but the zero field is simply not being looked at. The point is that the points are evenly distributed, not for example stacked at one side, and then being taken from the rest of the sides leading to a $(0,0,0,0,0,x)$ dice with $x$ being doubled each turn, and zeroes used as free rerolls.

Comment: I think the increment/decrement rule can be described thusly:  If you roll a $k$, then you add/subtract $1$ to/from the smallest/largest number currently on the die, and repeat this action $k$ times.  Or do you want the player to be able to *choose* the sides whose numbers get changed?  (If so, then any time you roll a $1$, you should decrement *that* side to a $0$, which effectively gives you a free roll.)

Comment: As he described you could decrement 1 to 0 but the next time you decrement you have to decrement any other number before you can decrement the 1 which is 0 now